# How to access the dictionary created in Django views in html

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

I have created a dictionary in Django views by fetching data from database. However, I am unable to comprehend how to use it to print it in the html as a table. Given below are the relevant files.

Views.py

```
if 'form1' in request.POST:
            d={}
            vendor_choice = request.POST["inlineDefaultRadiosExample"]
            date_choice = request.POST["inlineDefaultRadiosExample1"]
            x = employee.objects.all()
            count=0
            for i in x:
                if date_choice == 1:
                    d[count]=transaction.objects.filter(vendor_id=vendor_choice, emp_id = i.id, timestamp__gte = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=30))
                    count+=1
                elif date_choice == 2:
                    d[count]=transaction.objects.filter(vendor_id=vendor_choice, emp_id = i.id, timestamp__gte = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=60))
                    count+=1
                else:
                    d[count]=transaction.objects.filter(vendor_id=vendor_choice, emp_id = i.id, timestamp__gte = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=180))
                    count+=1
            return render(request, 'profiles/adminKaLogin.html', {'model':d})
```

The models.py

```
class vendor(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class employee(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class transaction(models.Model):
    vendor_id = models.ForeignKey(vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    emp_id = models.ForeignKey(employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    debit = models.IntegerField()
    credit = models.IntegerField()
    timestamp = models.DateField(("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)
```

The HTML

```
{% if model %}
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style = "padding: 20px;">Vendor ID</th>
                        <th style = "padding: 20px;">Employee ID</th>
                        <th style = "padding: 20px;">Debit</th>
                        <th style = "padding: 20px;">Credit</th>
                        <th style = "padding: 20px;">Time of transaction</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {% for i in model %}
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ i.vendor_id.id }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ i.emp_id.id }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ i.debit }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ i.credit }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ i.timestamp }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Class names should follow the `CamelCase` style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `i` variable contains queryset so you need to iterate over it one more time to get actual objects:

```
{% key, i in data.items %}
  {% for el in i %}
   <tr>
       <td style="text-align: center;">{{ el.vendor_id.id }}</td>
       <td style="text-align: center;">{{ el.emp_id.id }}</td>
       <td style="text-align: center;">{{ el.debit }}</td>
       <td style="text-align: center;">{{ el.credit }}</td>
       <td style="text-align: center;">{{ el.timestamp }}</td>
   </tr>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ah got it. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @DHRUVKAUSHAL also if you need to iterate over dict you can use `{% key, i in data.items %}` construction.:)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to loop over a dictionary as if its a list which might be your issue. You have `d = {}` where you should instead have `d = []` then the rest of your code should work

Comment: Hi. I changed d to [], and changed the d[count] to d.append. But I'm still not getting any output in the html.